# How to customize qtip toolbar to remove the close icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, qtip

Can i customize the qtip title bar in such a way that i dont have the CLOSE (X mark on top right corner) button in my qtip.

Ps: I have enabled close qtip on click and hence i dont want the CLOSE icon to be displayed. I tried removing it through javascript but the close icon is present till my partial view is loaded. I dont want it to appear from the start.

Comment: One solution is to look for the `CSS` class on Qtip.css file and edit it to remove the icon (if it's been adding in that way)

Comment: I dont want to remove it all together. I want that to happen for a particular page.